# Prevent react route onEnter

Tags: reactjs

I needed to check if a user has permission to access a route path, the permission data comes from the backend server.

Here is my method inside Routes class.

```
checkPermission( nextState ) {
  // Map path name to backend controller and action
  var backendControllerAction = ''
  const pathToGo = nextState.location.pathname
  if( pathToGo === '/warehouses' ) {
    backendControllerAction = 'WarehouseController@View'
  } else if ( pathToGo === '/warehouse/add' ) {
    backendControllerAction = 'WarehouseController@Create'
  } else if ( pathToGo === '/warehouse/update' ) {
    backendControllerAction = 'WarehouseController@Update'
  }
  restRequest( 'post', '/myperms', { path: backendControllerAction } ).then( ( res ) => {
    if( res !== true ) {
      window.location = '/#/dashboard'
    }
  } )
}
```

`restRequest` is a wrapper of axios, we use it to communicate with the backend.

In routes `checkPermission` will call `onEnter` event, like so:

```
<Route path='warehouses' onEnter={this.checkPermission} component={Warehouse}/>
```

But a redirect or returning false from the `checkPermission` wont prevent the route.

What i wanted to do is to prevent the route if the user has no permission to access the route and redirect the user to a different route instead.

Comment: An what about checking those permitions on componentWillMount from the loaded component instead? You might want to dispatch an action (if you are using redux or any flux-pattern) to redirect or redirect directly...